# How to remove inline element from bootstrap dropdown

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I have a simple question : when I use dropdown bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/dropdowns/#alignment-options, if I inspect the  element I can see some properties added inline :

```css
position: absolute;
inset: auto auto 0px 0px;
margin: 0px;
transform: translate(0px, -40px);
```

How can I remove this ?
I want to have my  element centered in relation with my button and not on the right or left.
So, for this,  want to use the position absolute and top and left not inset. Unless is there another possibility ?
I put bootstrap example behind.

```css
.dropup {
  margin-top: 8rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="btn-group dropup">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropup
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark" aria-labelledby="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLink">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

EDIT. I would like to have this :
[image]

Thanks a lot far answer.

Comment: I updated my answer for the sake of your requirement, please let me know if it matches with what you want or not

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

You can override `left` and `right` values on `dropdown-menu` to achieve it.

For example

```css
.dropup {
  margin-top: 8rem;
  margin-left: 8rem;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  right: auto !important;
  left: -50% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="btn-group dropup">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropup
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark" aria-labelledby="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLink">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

**OLD ANSWER**

All those inline CSS attributes are under `dropdown-menu`, so you can easily override it with [`!important`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_important.asp)

> The !important rule in CSS is used to add more importance to a property/value than normal. In fact, if you use the !important rule, it will override ALL previous styling rules for that specific property on that element!

For example

```
.dropdown-menu {
  inset: auto !important;
}
```

But you need to be careful with `!important`. That might cause some CSS problems if you try to style on the same class with the same attribute again on other places

Comment: Why margin-left -2.5rem ? If my button is larger it does not work and it is not responsive anyway.. I'll try to put 50% but it does not work

Comment: I just modified my answer with `left` and `right` values, could you check it out? The trade-off can be if the drop-down is on the furthest left or the furthest right, your dropdown box will be covered a bit @chtouk

Comment: Thanks. I choose finally to use popover bootstrap who is more appropriate for what I looking for. Thank you for your time